FirewallD and IPTables-NFT Chain Relationship
Something I am struggling to wrap my head around is the relationship between firewallD zone default behaviour and IPTables-NFT chain default behaviour.
I have setup a few firewalld direct rules that have been entered into NFTables (managed by IPTables-NFT). To my knoweledge the presidence of FirewallD rules goes:
Direct rules FirewallD IP Zones FirewallD Interface Zones By default the IPTables-NFT chain INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT policy are all set to ACCEPT, which I think means that anything that doesn't match an IPTables rule will just be accepted anyway. This doesn't appear to be the case. To add to this, none of the IPTables chains have any REJECT or DROP rules (apart from rejecting ICMP).
I have my interfaces in the PUBLIC FirewallD zone with no services defined and I have my public IP in the TRUSTED FirewallD zone. A basic configuration meaning that any service/protocol from my public IP is accepted, anything else is rejected by the PUBLIC zone.
Based on the above, if I were to SSH from any IP, I should be able to get in since the default policy of all chains are set to ACCEPT. Instead, it works as I would expect it to if the direct rules were not there at all (e.g. I can only SSH from my public IP and then anything else gets to the PUBLIC Zone in FirewallD and is rejected). This is how I would expect it to work...but with the addition of IPTables, I'm not entirely sure why.
So could someone explain to me what the IPTables chain policies actually do? Is it more that the ACCEPT policy is there just to allow traffic to pass to the next rule? That doesn't really make sense to me but if that were the case I would understand why it's working as it is since traffic not from my public IP will be going through my direct rules and ending up at my PUBLIC FirewallD zone which would reject it.

Would this be helpful: "Due to implementation details of netfilter inside the kernel, if FirewallBackend=nftables is used direct rules that ACCEPT packets don't actually cause the packets to be immediately accepted by the system. Those packets are still be subject to firewalld's nftables ruleset." https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct.html

@user202311 Thank you for this. It sort of helps but it seems as if firewalld picks and chooses when this happens. For example, I definitely have some direct ACCEPT rules that are adhered to as they aren't in any zones of firewalld (i.e. The ACCEPT rules accept traffic they are meant to and this isn't checked by FirewallD.)
